# How can I get selected file path from "file" tag?

Tags: java, html, jsp

My file file storage location is "E:\Records\DOCS\test.html"

How can I get Selected file path, following is my jsp tag

```
<form:input path="FileData" type="file"/>
```

I am selecting the test.html from above path and getting the selected file my model class as follows, I am able to get selected file name but along with file name I need full path.
How can I get full path in my model class ?

```
  private CommonsMultipartFile fileData;

    public CommonsMultipartFile getFileData()
    {
    return fileData;
    }
    public void setFileData(CommonsMultipartFile fileData)
    {
    System.out.println(fileData.getOriginalFilename()); // it gives output as test.html, I need full path
    return fileData;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filepaths of files selected in an `<input type='file' />` tags are on the client-side.  You don't need to know the filepath on the client-side, and the browser protects the client by preventing you from reading the path in any way in Javascript, and by not sending it in the request at all.  All you should be concerned with is where you are going to save the file on the server-side, and you obviously would not want to save it to the same place as where it was on the client (as this would give the user the power to overwrite any file on your server they wanted).  So you don't need to read any path.

Comment: yes, you are answer is perfect. but I want to store the selected path in database, It is my requirement. Is it possible ? give me some suggestions

Comment: Not possible.  Its a security feature of the browsers.  If they told you what the path was that the user selected the file from you could gain information like their username, possibly real name, and so on, from the path info. It would be a bad idea.